# Trying to populate database from Python - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Basically I'm scraping data off a leaderboard (`NYT crossword`) and trying to put it into a **database**. I realize a database is overkill for this but I'm trying to teach myself how to use `Postgres` via `SQLAlchemy`.

I'm able to **CREATE TABLE**, so I know I'm connected and the db connection is good.

Using `bs4`, I do a for loop and find each players name and time. But when I go to add those times to the db, I get :

> "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'"

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
db.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS solves (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        time INTEGER,
        date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);""")
    db.commit()
    for solver in solvers:
        name = solver.find('p', class_='lbd-score__name').text.strip()
        try:
            time = solver.find('p', class_='lbd-score__time').text.strip()
        except:
            time="--"
        if name.endswith("(you)"):
            name_split = name.split()
            name = name_split[0]
        if name in players:
            daytimes.append([month,day,year,name,time])
            db.execute("INSERT INTO solves (name, time) VALUES (?, ?)", (name, time))
            db.commit()
```

I've tried a number of things, but generally get the same result (though sometimes it says `"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'"` (instead of tuple). I've tried using `%s` instead of `?`, tried setting it up like this:

```
        entry = (name,time)
        sql = """
            INSERT INTO solves (name,time) 
            VALUES (%s,%s)"""
        db.execute(sql, entry)
        db.commit()
```

But I keep getting that `AttributeError`.

The only way I can get it to work is if I do it this way:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO solves (name, time) VALUES ('kyle', '45')")
```

But then obviously I'm not using the values I'm scraping.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Sqlalchemy does things a little strangely.  They expect you to use the abstract `db.execute( table.insert(), {'name':name, 'time':time})`.  You should be able to tweak your code by doing `db.execute('INSERT etc', (1, name), (2, time))`

Comment: This didn't exactly answer it for me, but it pushed me in the right direction! Basically had to create new table from a class using `declarative base`, do a `base.metadata.create_all(db)` and then `entry = Player(name=name, time=time)`. Appreciate your help Tim!